# Constructing a Countable Base from a Union of Finite Open Covers

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

My question comes form the second section of the first chapter of $\textit{Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology}$. To paraphrase, the texts essentially says that you could easily verify the following lemma implies the theorem. They state:

(Miscenko's Lemma) For any infinite cardial $\kappa$ and any set $E$ with a collection $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$ such that $\text{ord}(p, \mathscr{A}) = |\{ A \in \mathscr{A} : p \in A \} | \leq \kappa$ for every $p \in E$, then the number of minimal finite covers of $E$ by members of $\mathscr{A}$ is bounded by $\kappa$.

(Miscenko's Theorem) Every compact space with a point countable base has a countable base.

My attempt is the following. Allow $X$ to be a compact space with point countable basis $\mathscr{B}$, and set $\mathscr{B}' = \bigcup\{ B \subset \mathscr{B} : B \text{ is a minimal finite cover of } X\}$.

I'd like to show that $\mathscr{B}'$ is the desired countable basis of $X$. It certainly covers $X$, is nonempty, and countable by the lemma above. The only problem is that I'm not convinced if it satisfies the most more important property of being a basis. I'd like to show this directly. So assume $B_1, B_2 \in \mathscr{B}'$ with $B_1 \cap B_2 \neq \emptyset$. We know that there exists a $B_3 \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Can we also show $B_3 \in \mathscr{B}'$? I'm attempting to use the compactness of $X$ to construct some minimal finite cover that contains $B_3$ to guarantee that $B_3 \in \mathscr{B}'$, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\ x\in B_3\ $ and $\ \mathscr{C}=\left\{\,B\in\mathscr{B}\,|\,x\not\in B\right\}\ $  Since $\ \mathscr{B}\ $ is a basis, $\ \bigcup\mathscr{C}=X\setminus\{x\}\ $ and $\ \mathscr{C}\cup \{B_3\}\ $ is a cover of $\ X $, which must have a finite subcover, $\ \mathscr{C}'\ $, since $\ X\ $ is compact. Since $\ B_3\ $ is the only member of $\ \mathscr{C}\cup \{B_3\}\ $ that contains $\ x\ $, it must be a non-redundant member of $\ \mathscr{C}'\ $.  If $\ \mathscr{C}'\ $ contains any redundant members, one or more can be successively removed to obtain a minimal finite cover of $\ X\ $ that contains $\ B_3\ $.  Therefore $\ B_3\in\mathscr{B}'\ $.

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely forgot we are clearly working in a Hausdorff space, so I was not assuming that singletons were closed.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to have to admit not noticing that my proof implicitly assumed a separation axiom (I believe  $\ T_1\ $  is sufficient). In the article you cite from *Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology*, R. Hodel takes compact spaces to be Hausdorff by definition (p.6), so it's certainly legitimate to assume that in the proof. However, it's not obvious to me that the space would be Hausdorff (or $\ T_1\ $) otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The result holds for $T_1$ compact spaces. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a point countable base of $X$, where $X$ is your $T_1$ compact space, and let $\mathcal{B}'$ be the union of $\mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ the family of all finite minimal covers of the space by basic open sets from $\mathcal{B}$. By Miscenko's Lemma, $\mathcal{C}$ is
countable - thus, $\mathcal{B}'$ is countable as well, as being a union of a countable family of finite sets.

Also, clearly $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}$.

The main point is:  you do not need to worry about "directly checking that $\mathcal{B}'$ is a base", because we have a neat argument to show that, indeed, $\mathcal{B}' = \mathcal{B}$.

Indeed: let $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and fix $x \in \mathcal{B}$.

The closed subspace $X \setminus B$ is compact, and for all $y \in X \setminus B$ we may fix a basic open set $B_y \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \notin B_y$ (and here is the point where we use the separation axiom
hypothesis!). Thus, there is a finite family $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\} \subseteq X \setminus B$ such that $\{B_{y_1}, B_{y_2}, \ldots, B_{y_n}\}$ covers $X \setminus B$.

Notice that $\{B\} \cup \{B_{y_1},\ldots,B_{y_n}\}$ is finite open cover of $X$ by basic open sets from $\mathcal{B}$, and by construction the open set $B$ cannot be discarded if we proceed to get a minimal cover included in it - because $B$ is the only open set covering the fixed point $x$!

It follows that there is a finite set $A \subseteq \{y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\}$ such that $\{B\} \cup \{B_y: y \in A\}$ is a finite minimal open cover of $X$ by basic open sets from $\mathcal{B}$, so $\{B\} \cup \{B_y: y \in A\} \in \mathcal{C}$ and $B \in \bigcup \mathcal{C} =\mathcal{B}'$.